# Charts iOS Horizontal Bar Chart Value Labels Cut Off

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-charts

I have set up a Horizontal Bar Chart and placed a custom value in each bar.
Unfortunately most of the small values are not properly rendered into the bar.
Is there a way to set the minimum length of a bar to avoid this problem (or something else).

I tried out lots of variations to set the offset and `minValue`, but with no success.
If please someone could point me in the right direction. It would be appreciated a lot.
Thank you

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Please find below the code to reproduce this behaviour.
The dictionary consists of names and values (e.g. 569, 714, 1444, etc)

```
- (void)showBarlineReportDoctorsWithView:(HorizontalBarChartView *)viewChart andDataSource:(NSDictionary *)dictDataSource
{
    viewChart.data = nil;
    viewChart.noDataText = @"";
    viewChart.chartDescription.enabled = NO;
    viewChart.drawGridBackgroundEnabled = NO;
    viewChart.dragEnabled = YES;
    [viewChart setScaleEnabled:NO];
    viewChart.pinchZoomEnabled = NO;
    viewChart.delegate = self;
    viewChart.drawBarShadowEnabled = NO;
    viewChart.drawValueAboveBarEnabled = NO;
    viewChart.legend.enabled = NO;
    viewChart.highlightPerDragEnabled = NO;
    viewChart.highlightFullBarEnabled = NO;
    viewChart.highlightPerTapEnabled = NO;
    
    viewChart.leftAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = NO;
    viewChart.leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = NO;
    viewChart.leftAxis.drawZeroLineEnabled = NO;
    viewChart.leftAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = NO;
    viewChart.leftAxis.drawBottomYLabelEntryEnabled = NO;
    viewChart.leftAxis.drawLimitLinesBehindDataEnabled = NO;
    viewChart.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0.0;
    viewChart.leftAxis.enabled = NO;
    
    viewChart.rightAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = NO;
    viewChart.rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = NO;
    viewChart.rightAxis.drawZeroLineEnabled = YES;
    viewChart.rightAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = NO;
    viewChart.rightAxis.axisMinimum = 0.0;
    viewChart.rightAxis.enabled = YES;
    
    viewChart.xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = YES;
    viewChart.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = NO;
    viewChart.xAxis.labelFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:10.5];
    viewChart.xAxis.labelTextColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    viewChart.xAxis.labelPosition = XAxisLabelPositionBottom;
    viewChart.xAxis.labelWidth = 300;
    viewChart.xAxis.labelHeight = 30;
    
    viewChart.xAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = YES;
    viewChart.xAxis.drawLimitLinesBehindDataEnabled = NO;
    viewChart.xAxis.granularity = 1.0;
    viewChart.xAxis.labelCount = dictDataSource.count;
    
    //Sort the dictionary to its values descending
    NSArray *blockSortedKeys = [dictDataSource keysSortedByValueUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2)
                                {
                                    // Switching the order of the operands reverses the sort direction
                                    return [obj2 compare:obj1];
                                }];
    NSMutableArray *yVals = NSMutableArray.new;
    NSMutableArray<NSString *> *xLabels = NSMutableArray.new;
    int i = 0;
    for (NSString *key in blockSortedKeys) {
        double dblValue = [dictDataSource[key] doubleValue];
        [yVals addObject:[[BarChartDataEntry alloc] initWithX:i y:dblValue]];
        NSString *strKeyAbbr = [IOSUtilities CutTextToRect:key MaxWidth:viewChart.xAxis.labelWidth withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:10.5]];
        [xLabels addObject:strKeyAbbr];
        i++;
    }

    if (yVals.count > 0)
    {
        viewChart.xAxis.valueFormatter = [[ChartIndexAxisValueFormatter alloc] initWithValues:xLabels];
        BarChartDataSet *set1 = nil;
        set1 = [[BarChartDataSet alloc] initWithValues:yVals label:@"DataSet"];
        set1.drawIconsEnabled = YES;
        set1.drawValuesEnabled = YES;
        set1.valueTextColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:229.0 green:252.0 blue:255.0 alpha:1.0];
        set1.valueFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20.0];
        
        NSNumberFormatter *pFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        pFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;
        pFormatter.currencySymbol = @"€ ";
        pFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0;
        
        ChartDefaultValueFormatter *chartFormatter = [[ChartDefaultValueFormatter alloc] init];
        chartFormatter.formatter = pFormatter;
        [set1 setColor:[IOSUtilities getBlueIPraxColor]];
        
        NSArray *dataSets = @[set1];
        BarChartData *data = [[BarChartData alloc] initWithDataSets:dataSets];
        [data setValueFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20.0]];
         [data groupBarsFromX:0.0 groupSpace:10.0 barSpace:10.0];
        [data setValueFormatter:chartFormatter];
        viewChart.data = data;
    }
    [viewChart notifyDataSetChanged];
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code on how are you trying to achieve this?

Comment: thanks for your answer <3. Just edited the question and added the code requested :)

Comment: [BarChartDataEntry alloc] initWithX:i y:dblValue], You need to adjust the dblValue according to your requirement.